# LMI for maximum singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, singular-values, linear-matrix-inequality

The (maximum singular value) matrix norm constraint $\|A(x)\|<1$, where $A(x) \in \mathbb R^{p \times q}$ depends affinely on $x$, is represented as the following linear matrix inequality (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & A(x)  \\
    A(x)^T       & I  \\
\end{bmatrix} >0$$

since $\|A(x)\|<1$ is equivalent to $I-AA^T > 0$. Why?

I would like to understand this statement of LMI. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: What's the other side of the inequality here?

Comment: >0 I edites, sorry.

Comment: What's a LMI? (Not all abbreviations are 100% standard.)

Comment: Linear matrix inequalities

Comment: So in other words, $\begin{bmatrix} I & A \\ A^T & I \end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite? Then I can tell you how to handle the second part: $\| A \|_2$ is the largest singular value, which is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A A^T$. If $\| A \|_2<1$ then all eigenvalues of $A A^T$ are less than $1$ so all eigenvalues of $I-AA^T$, which are $1$ minus eigenvalues of $A A^T$, are positive.

Comment: Bus can I see $I-AA^T$ as the determinant of that matrix positive definite?

Comment: The determinant is a number, regardless of writing things as block matrices. A different way to view it is to think of this as $I$ plus the positive definite matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & A^T \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ whose eigenvalues are the singular values of $A$.

Comment: Ok, just a merely question, if A is a square matrix and symmetric the A is symmetric ? I'm sure that it is true but I would like know your opinion , ty.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963711/339790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer is wrong. Here is the correct one.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & A(x)  \\
    A(x)^T       & I  \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & 0  \\
    A(x)^T       & I  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & 0  \\
    0       & I-A(x)^TA(x)  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & A(X)  \\
    0       & I  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus $\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & A(x)  \\
    A(x)^T       & I  \\
\end{bmatrix} \gt 0$ is equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix}I-A(x)^TA(x)\end{bmatrix} \gt 0$ and @Ian in his comment proved the second part.

Comment: How do you divide the matrix in the other three matrix blocks ? With Schroeder complement?

Comment: Do you get* and Schur complement *

Comment: Yes, by using Schur complement.

Answer (score 1):

because $\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & A(x)  \\
    A(x)^T       & I  \\
\end{bmatrix} $ is positive definite. For any non-empty vector,

$$\begin{bmatrix} z_1 &z_2 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & A(x)  \\
    A(x)^T       & I  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$= ||z_1||^2+||z_2||^2+2||z_1^TA^Tz_2||$$
$$= ||z_1||^2+||z_2||^2+2||z_1||\cdot||A^TA||\cdot||z_2|| \gt 0$$